# How can I change proxy from javascript(using an addon)?

Tags: javascript, firefox

How can I change Firefox proxy settings from javascript(using an addon)?

Comment: You can't. Browsers strictly limit javascript to reach *that* areas.

Comment: If there's an add-on that allows Javascript code to do that, I certainly don't want it in my browser.

Comment: There is an Addon called FoxyProxy i think will help you for proxy settings, and there are another addons for that, but JavaScript ! how come ? you can't ! Impossible !

Comment: @all: Well, Firefox addons are mostly implemented using JavaScript and are executed with special privileges... so that should be possible somehow. If I understand you correctly, you want to create an addon?

Comment: For clarification, there is a difference to write/use such an add-on for Firefox or, say, Chrome. the reason is that Chrome uses underlined OS for its proxy configuration (at least on Windows), whereas Firefox has an additional layer built-in. The FoxyProxy add-on, IIRC, changes the current proxy configuration in that layer, leaving the system configuration intact.

Answer (score 2):

Nowadays(2013) it's very easy, using the latest SDK(1.14) you can do it with a few lines of code:

```
const {Cu} = require("chrome");
Cu.import("resource://gre/modules/Services.jsm");
Services.prefs.setCharPref("network.proxy.http", proxy_ip);
Services.prefs.setIntPref("network.proxy.http_port", proxy_port);
Services.prefs.setIntPref("network.proxy.type", 1);
```

You can also set ftp and ssl proxy IP and port if you want. The proxy_ip and proxy_port variables contain what their name describes.

That code snippet was copied from a new [proxy add-on for Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/one-click-proxy/), but any extension that uses the latest SDK is going to do the same.

Answer (score 1):

simple

```
netscape.security.PrivilegeManager
  .enablePrivilege("UniversalBrowserAccess UniversalXPConnect");
  var prefs = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/preferences-service;1"]
              .getService(Components.interfaces.nsIPrefBranch);

     prefs.setIntPref("network.proxy.type", 1);


 prefs.setCharPref("network.proxy.http", "5.5.5.5");
 prefs.setIntPref("network.proxy.http_port", "80");

prefs.setCharPref("javascript.enabled", "true");
```

Answer (score 0):

As stated by others: FoxyProxy performs this role from a user perspective. It's certainly possible to edit the configurations using the [nsIPrefService](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/nsIPrefService) if you want to do it from your own extension for some other purpose - but it's very tricky not to damage the user experience this way (eg. overriding another extension unintentionally) as you are editing the browser's global state.